# check on indices of matrix/array and then check for some condition

Tags: python, numpy

This code converts a square matrix to strict lower triangular matrix (lower elements to 0)

```
a=np.random.randn(9).reshape((3,3))

a
Out[61]: 
array([[-0.18314209,  0.3710528 , -1.46067261],
       [-0.55834476, -1.41924213, -0.04127718],
       [ 0.40134248, -0.41759044,  1.83573994]])

def subs_tri_0(mat,i,j): mat[i,j] = 0

[subs_tri_0(a,i,j) for i,j in product(xrange(a.shape[0]),xrange(a.shape[1])) if i > j]
Out[63]: [None, None, None]

a
Out[64]: 
array([[-0.18314209,  0.3710528 , -1.46067261],
       [ 0.        , -1.41924213, -0.04127718],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  1.83573994]])
```

Is there a way to this using short and sweet where?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't use `numpy.where`, but you could use [`numpy.tril_indices`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tril_indices.html) to set the lower triangular to zero:

```
>>> a
array([[ 0.05559341, -1.93583316, -1.19666435],
       [-0.33450047,  0.63275874,  0.77152195],
       [-0.73106122, -1.57602057,  0.41878224]])
>>> a[np.tril_indices(3, k=-1)] = 0
>>> a
array([[ 0.05559341, -1.93583316, -1.19666435],
       [ 0.        ,  0.63275874,  0.77152195],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.41878224]])
```

Note that you need to pass `k=-1` to `numpy.tril_indices` to not include the diagonal.

Comment: @user2290820: yes, Numpy to the rescue again :) I was unclear if your question was asking for a simple method for modifying the lower triangular, but I take it that's all you wanted to know?

Comment: ultimately yes. but i also googled for ways to loop indices in numpy w/o calling for loop or a fast C API loop. I think numpy doesnt stil have enumerating through indices. say you just want to print the indices of an array in numpy. say where([i,j] in a is sm condition,result1,result2) ; You cud do where(array) instead

Answer (score 0):

Found the result. Although I'm gona go ahead with @mdml solution. which is to the point btw.

This is just a positive side effect of looping through indices to check for row,col conditions. perhaps anyone could use it for some other meaningful purpose where tril and triu methods are not the case.

```
a=np.random.randn(9).reshape((3,3))

r,c = where(a)
where((r>c).reshape(a.shape),0,a)
Out[169]: 
array([[ 1.49230558,  0.6321149 ,  0.05299907],
       [ 0.        ,  0.14736346,  0.42516369],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        , -0.6878655 ]])
```